# What is wrong with the way I am passing this @Input in Angular?

Tags: angular

I am trying to pass a model from one component to another in Angular 5.

I have a base page that hosts two other pages. The html looks like this:

```
<div [hidden]="!loading">
<page-one *ngIf="!showPageTwo"
             (model)="model"
             (next)="showPageTwo = true">
</page-one>
<page-two *ngIf="showPageTwo"
           [model]="model">
</page-two>
```

Page one looks like this:

```
import section....

@Component({
selector: 'page-one',
templateUrl: './pageOneComponent.html'
})
export class PageOneComponent {

public model: ExampleViewModel;
public otherModel: NotTheModelThatIsImportantHere;

@Output('next') onNextEmitter = new EventEmitter<void>();
@Output("model") modelEmitter = new EventEmitter<ExampleViewModel>();

contructor ....

onSubmit() {
    this.exampleService.doSomething(this.otherModel).then(response => {
        this.model = response;
        this.modelEmitter.emit(this.model);
        this.onNextEmitter.emit();                
    });
}
```

Page Two looks like this:

```
imports...

@Component({
selector: 'page-two',
templateUrl: './pageTwoComponent.html'
})

export class PageTwoComponent {
public copyOfModel: ExampleViewModel;

@Input() model: ExampleViewModel;

constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.copyOfModel = this.model; //this is undefined
}
```

Here is what is really confusing me.  If I change the base page like so:

```
<page-one *ngIf="!showPageTwo"
         (model)="model = $event"
         (next)="showPageTwo = true">
</page-one>
```

And then change page one like this:

```
onSubmit() {
    this.exampleService.doSomething(this.otherModel).then(response => {
        this.modelEmitter.emit(response);
        this.onNextEmitter.emit();                
    });
}
```

Then the @Input value is not undefined.  It is the model I was hoping to pass.  So why am I unable to pass a property like this, but I can pass the server response?  I am not understanding this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line doesn't do anything: `(model)="model"`. You have to set the model to something (e.g. `(model)="model = 1"`).

In your case you want it to be the value that was emitted from your `this.modelEmitter.emit(response);` line. In Angular, your emitted value is accessed in your template code for that output via the `$event` variable.

Putting this altogether you needed to set your template up as you now have it: `(model)="model = $event"`.

Here is the Angular cookbook for component interaction around this topic: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event

Comment: Yes,this was it. Thank you. I had searched through the docs but did not find the helpful page you linked to.